# Regular expression: Match domain in URI

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

How can I match the domain part only of a URI with regular expressions? I see lots of examples but the mutch the subdomain too. What I am looking to do is to capture only the domain but I can't figure it out.

So, for example `http://foo.google.tdl/bar` should match only `google`.

As a secondary question, I am looking to implement this on a VB.NET program. Would there be some other way to do it without regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
^[^\/]+:\/\/[^\/]*?\.?([^\/.]+)\.[^\/.]+(?::\d+)?\/
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/Uv5ON7eAz4

```
^             # Match the beginning of the string
[^\/]+:\/\/   # Match the protocol (e.g. http://)
[^\/]*?       # Non-greedy match of the sub-domains
\.?           # Optional . (for when a sub-domain is used)
([^\/.]+)     # Group the domain
\.            # . between domain and tld
[^\/.]+       # tld
(?::\d+)?     # Optional port
\/            # Slash between tld and path
```

Comment: So example.co.uk would give a domain of "co". That can't be right

Comment: @justintime Good point. To solve this accurately you'd need a list of all the tld's then, because otherwise how would you handle `foo.bit.ly` for example?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know VB.NET, but if you only want the domain part, and you are sure to always have the same protocol, you can achieve your goal in four simple steps:

1. Strip the protocol from the URI (http:// in your case);
2. Split the remaining part at the first / occurrence and keep the first part;
3. Split the remaining part at the last . occurrence and keep the first part.
4. Split the remaining part at the last . occurrence and keep the last part.

In python this would be roughly equivalent to:

```
uri = uri.replace('http://', '')
uri = uri.split('/', 1)[0]
uri = uri.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
uri = uri.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
```

Clearly this only works for your specific case (http prefix, top-level domain), but is general enough to work if the provided uri does not specify a protocol, has no path, has no subdomains,...